# Recurrence relation with $n$ in the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have the following recursive sequence:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
a_{n+1}=a_n-a_n^2,\\a_0=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
I proved that $0<a_{n+1}<a_n$ and that $a_n\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ but how can I prove that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}na_n=1?
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

By Stolz-Cesaro we have

$$\frac{(n+1)-n}{\frac1{a_{n+1}}-\frac1{a_n}}=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\to 1\implies na_n \to 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Because $(a_n)$ tends to $0$, you have
$$\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{a_n} = \frac{1}{a_n - a_n^2}- \frac{1}{a_n} =\frac{1}{a_n} \left(  \frac{1}{1 - a_n}- 1\right) = \frac{1}{a_n} \left(  1+ a_n + o(a_n)- 1\right) = 1 + o(1)$$

Therefore
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \left(\frac{1}{a_{n+1}} - \frac{1}{a_n} \right) = 1$$

So you can use Cesaro to deduce that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{1}{na_n} = 1$$

which implies that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} na_n = 1$$